# Include "view" function in redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In an application dealing with posts and comments, I want to keep my state in a flat, normalized structure to be as flexible as possible. Specifically, I want to have all posts and comments as key-value pairs, where the key is the id of the post or comment and the value is the post or comment. I.e., my state looks like this:

```
state = {
    posts: new Map(),
    comments: new Map()
},
```

This state structure simplifies most of the reducer cases. In the components however, I repeatedly need to do the following to get an array of the posts or comments:

```
Array.from(this.props.posts.values())
```

Where `this.props.posts` are the redux state's posts mapped to the props of the particular component.

Is there a way to add the last code snippet to the state, much like a view in a relational database? I tried

```
state = {
    posts: new Map(),
    comments: new Map(),
    postArray: () => { return Array.from(posts.values()) }
},
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs, specifically the section on [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html).

We recommend that a typical normalized state section should like like:

```
users : {
    byId : {},
    allIds : []
}
```

You should also use [memoized "selector" functions](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) to encapsulate the process of deriving data from the store state.

Also,  I personally am a big fan of using the [Redux-ORM library](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) as an abstraction layer for managing normalized data in a Redux store.  My ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux) demonstrates how to use it.

I have links to additional articles on reducers, selectors, and normalization in the [Redux Reducers and Selectors](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-reducers-selectors.md) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a higher order component to wrap your component and inject the additional prop in it. I would suggest looking at [withProps](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withprops) from the `recompose` library for doing this in a succinct manner.